# Example of an infinite ring with an odd number of units?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have my abstract algebra exam online this thursday and was hoping to get some confirmation on some of these short questions.

**Is there an example of an infinite ring with an odd number of units?**

Every non-field example I can think of simply has two: $\{\pm 1\}$

**Is there a field of characterstic $7$ which has an element $x$ such that $x+x+x=0$?**

I think the answer must be no. The only fields I have in mind are $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{7\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{7\mathbb{Z}[X]}$(rational functions).

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}_2$ has only one unit, $1$ since $-1=1$ here.  Can you use this to create an infinite ring that would still have only $1$ as its unit?

If the characteristic is $7$, then $7x=x + x + ... + x =0$ for all $x$.  This means the order of every element under addition must divide 7, so either order 1 or 7.  You could of course let $x=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$, but I assume they don't want a zero solution.

Comment: How about an infinite ring with exactly 3 units?

Comment: I have to say, I am worried I am doing an online exam for you.  I think you should think about these problems a bit on your own.  You also are supposed to make a new post for each question so people can find them later.

Comment: Just trying to study and not very interested in ring theory I'm afraid.

Comment: Gotcha.  You can construct fields of any size $p^n$ with $p$ a prime. So one of size $4$ should have 3 units because $0$ is not a unit.  This same trick should be able to be used here then.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, more generally we have

> There is no ring of characteristic $7$ which has a nonzero element $x$ such that $x+x+x=0$.

Indeed, $7x=0$ and $3x=0$ imply $x=\gcd(7,3)x=0$.